How to mock custom external hook libraries at least twice?
Right I've got this:
jest.mock("@apollo/client", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("@apollo/client"),
  useReactiveVar: () => {
    return { ...data, bool: false }
  },
}))

Easily mocked
but if I want to pass in bool as true next time to test a second test, how do I do that?
I thought I could attach useReactiveVarMock as a jest.fn but it wouldn't let me do that

"It wouldn't let me" as in "It gave me an error message that I didn't bother reading"?

If it's not an ECMAScriptModule you should be able to do it if you prefix the variable with mock instead of suffixing it. Jest will hoist the variable before the jest.mock call
